# Gamma PDF plots

Tags: r

I need help in plotting gamma distribution PDFs in R or RStudio. I have four different gamma distributions listed below. I want to plot their PDFs on the same axis with different colours and also add a legend.

1. gamma(0.5,0.33)
2. gamma(2.0,0.88)
3. gamma(2.4,1.22)
4. gamma(1.8,1.10)

Comment: Hey Jon, take a look at this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190465/how-to-draw-fitted-graph-and-actual-graph-of-gamma-distribution-in-one-plot and good luck with your homework ;).

Comment: I already had a look at that question but didn'y find it helpful.

Comment: See this https://statisticsglobe.com/draw-multiple-function-curves-to-same-plot-in-r

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?  `curve()` and `legend()` should be all you need to get this done.

Comment: I'm using the lines(x,dgamma(x,0.5,0.33)) which should give me the plot for the pdf of the first distribution but problem is I haven't been given the values for x in the question as you can see. all i have are the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want, but be careful with the parametrization of rate and scale = 1/rate (use just one).

```
x <- (1:1000)/100
y1 <- dgamma(x = x, 0.5, 0.33)
y2 <- dgamma(x = x, 2.0, 0.88)
y3 <- dgamma(x = x, 2.4, 1.22)
y4 <- dgamma(x = x, 1.8, 1.10)

pdf(file = 'my-gamma-plot.pdf')
plot(x, y1, type = 'l')
lines(x, y2, type = 'l', col = 2)
lines(x, y3, type = 'l', col = 3)
lines(x, y4, type = 'l', col = 4)
legend("topright",
  legend = c('gamma1', 'gamma2', 'gamma3', 'gamma4'), 
       col = c(1:4),
  lty = 1, cex = 0.8)
dev.off()
```

[image: gamma-plot.pdf]

Answer (score 0):

A base R option with `curve`

```
f1 <- function(x) dgamma(x, 0.5, 0.33)
f2 <- function(x) dgamma(x, 2, 0.88)
f3 <- function(x) dgamma(x, 2.4, 1.22)
f4 <- function(x) dgamma(x, 1.8, 1.1)
curve(f1, 0, 10)
curve(f2, 0, 10, add = TRUE, lty = "dotdash")
curve(f3, 0, 10, add = TRUE, lty = "dashed")
curve(f4, 0, 10, add = TRUE, lty = "dotted")
legend(
  "center",
  legend = c("gamma(0.5,0.33)", "gamma(2,0.88)", "gamma(2.4,1.22)", "gamma(1.8.1.1)"),
  box.lty = 0,
  cex = 1.5,
  lty = c("solid", "dotdash", "dashed", "dotted")
)
```

[image]